# What is the best way to remove this table partition?

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, sql-server-2016

I have to change a partitioned table in Sql Server 2008 R2 to a normal table to make my database compatible with Sql Server 2016 Standard Edition.

Actually the table has 5 partitions with the following number of rows:

```
> boundary, rows 
2009-01-01 00:00:00.000 419 
2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 386031 
2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 1307990 
2012-01-01 00:00:00.000 673183 
NULL                    9743057
```

The table contains a BLOB (image) column. The total size of the table is around 25 GB.

I have read through the question [How to remove a table partition](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69672/how-to-remove-a-table-partition) but although it has answered there is no accepted answer and the answers do not address my question entirely.

I realized the [ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION MERGE RANGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms186307.aspx) command, but I do not really understand what will happen. Will the data be merget into one of the existing filegroups and afterwards I will still have a partitioned table?

Do I instead have to copy all the data into a new table with the same structure (may take quite a while...)?

I will have to perform this action during a downtime, so I need a procedure that is as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To remove table partitioning entirely, rebuild all indexes with a filegroup specification instead of partition scheme.  Use `CREATE INDEX` with the `DROP_EXISTING=ON` option to do that efficiently.

See [MSDN: `CREATE INDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) page for syntax.

Comment: Could you perform the following procedure? 1.Rebuild Clustered index with online ON/Drop_Existing ON to a new or existing filegroup 2.rebuild nonclustered indexes with online on/Drop_Existing ON to the filegroup 3. remove the former partition files from the database. 4. Detach, copy and attach DB on new Standard server.  ?

Comment: @Magier, yes you can use that procedure. Removing files and filegroups is optional.  If you perform the operation during a maintenance window, `ONLINE=OFF` (the default option) should be used, which might run faster.  You could also used backup/restore instead of detach/attach to move the database to the SE server.  Query  `sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features` to make sure no other EE-only features are used.